# Value in insert statement doesn't match value inserted

Tags: mysql, insert

After I execute the following query:

```
INSERT INTO `temp` (`id`, `user_id`) VALUES (110, 100003568483914);
```

The result in database is :

```
**id    user_id**
110 2147483647
```

Why is the value in the table different from what was inserted?

Comment: Two questions: first, are you getting an error after your insert? Second, is `id` an auto-incrementing integer column?

Comment: int type fields signed range is -2147483648 to 2147483647
So u r getting the max value. convert it to bigint.

Answer (score 1):

do `describe temp` you'll see that `user_id` is signed INT, ie 31 bit for the number + one bit for the sign, which give you range from -2^31 to 2^31 -1 (2147483647 = 2^31 -1).

what you need to do is to change the column type of `user_id`; it seems that you're storing facebook user ids for which I would recommend using strings; you'll never need to do any arithmetic on these anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Change the field type to LONG or BIGINT or unsigned INT (unsigned INT is probably sufficient).